# Combining 2 dictionaries in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns of dictionaries. I am trying to create a 3rd column where each row is the first two columns rows' dictionaries combined into one dictionary (they all have the same key). My first attempt was:

```
nf = defaultdict(list)

for row in range(len(df)):
  for i in (df['D1'][row],df['D2'][row]):
    for key, value in i.items():
      df['D3'] = nf[key].append(value)
```

The output is:

```
                   D1                     D2    D3
0  {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}  {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12}  None
1  {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 6}  {0: 13, 1: 14, 2: 15}  None
2  {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 9}  {0: 16, 1: 17, 2: 18}  None
```

I want D3 to look like:

```
D3
{0: [1,10], 1: [2,11], 2: [3,12]}
{0: [4,13], 1: [5,14], 2: [6,15]}
...
```

Be advised that this is just sample data, my actual data has 43,000 rows, where there are 2 columns with dictionaries in each row, and each row has a different length dictionary but are the same length as the dictionary next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list for the D3 entries by looping simultaneously through D1 and D2. And for each row loop through the keys:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'D1': [{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 6}, {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 9}],
                   'D2': [{0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12}, {0: 13, 1: 14, 2: 15}, {0: 16, 1: 17, 2: 18}]})
df['D3'] = [{k: [d1i[k], d2i[k]] for k in d1i.keys()} for d1i, d2i in zip(df['D1'], df['D2'])]
```

Which makes `df['D3']`:

```py
0    {0: [1, 10], 1: [2, 11], 2: [3, 12]}
1    {0: [4, 13], 1: [5, 14], 2: [6, 15]}
2    {0: [7, 16], 1: [8, 17], 2: [9, 18]}
```

The code assumes that for each row, all keys of D1 are also present in D2.

To better see what's going on, a longer version might help:

```py
d3_list = []
for d1i, d2i in zip(df['D1'], df['D2']):
    d3i = {k: [d1i[k], d2i[k]] for k in d1i.keys()}
    d3_list.append(d3i)
df['D3'] = d3_list
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes it does it work out great, thanks.